# Can't access to UserRepository property inside a custom security expression

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I had a problem on my SpringBoot server REST API. In fact, I created a custom security expression in order to check if a specific user is allowed to access to a ressource (this is not a role).

So my class extends **SecurityExpressionRoot** and implements **MethodSecurityExpressionOperations**. Everything is working fine (method called successfully) but I can"t use my UserRepository attribute: it's null.

So my question is, how to be able to use **UserRepository** instance inside a **custom security expression** ?

Thanks in advance !

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {
    public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
        super(authentication);
    }

    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository; // This is always null

    @Override
    public void setFilterObject(Object o) { }

    @Override
    public Object getFilterObject() { return null; }

    @Override
    public void setReturnObject(Object o) { }

    @Override
    public Object getReturnObject() { return null; }

    @Override
    public Object getThis() { return null; }

    public boolean isValidated() {
        UserDetails principalUser = (UserDetails)authentication.getPrincipal();

        Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findOneByLogin(principalUser.getUsername()); // Username is found here
        return userFromDatabase.map(user -> { // Not executed because userFromDatabase is null :/
            return true;
        }).orElseThrow(() -> {
            return new UsernameNotFoundException("user was not found in the database");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot`  must be a spring component ! and to inject your `UserRepository`, you can do it by using `@Autowired`

Comment: @TinyOS Thanks for your (very) fast reply ! I tried to add `@Component` at the top of the class & set `@Autowired` to UserRepository and I have an exception when starting my server: `Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityConfig': **Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess` (sorry I'm very new to SpringBoot, coming from Node.JS :p)

Comment: I'm not familiar with SecurityExpressionRoot but that does not feel the right way to go.

The user should be already in the UserDetails at  this time, thus no call to database should be done in that expression.

Look for DaoAuthenticationProvider and DaoAuthenticationProvider (spring security classes) for some pointers on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I used this "hack" because user's informations in UserDetails was not updated (it seems user's informations was not refreshed from the database). I'm going to check `DaoAuthenticationProvider` thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make your class a spring component, the best approach is to pass `UserRepository` also in the constructor and pass it from a service as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

the `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot` must be a spring component and inject the `UserRepository` by using `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can apply what is done in the link https://medium.com/@islamboulila/how-to-create-a-custom-security-expression-method-in-spring-security-e5b6353f062f
In the MethodSecurityConfig she passes ApplicationContext to MethodSecurityExpressionHandler. And inside of MethodSecurityExpressionHandler she gets UserService bean from ApplicationContext and passes to CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot via setter.